# Calculating probability based on mixed variables

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Assume there are $K$ people and iid. parameters $a_1,\ldots,a_K$ associated to them with $a_i \sim U(0,1)$. Person $i$ observes his own fixed $a_i$ with some noise: 
\begin{equation}
X^{(1)}_i= a_i+ e^{(1)}_i, 
\end{equation}
where the $e_i$ is an error terms distributed normally with $N(0, v)$. He learns $X^{(1)}_i$.

After observing $X^{(1)}_i$, person $i$ would like to calculate the probability that next time the persons $1,\ldots,K$ get signals (denote the new signals by $X^{(2)}_i$), his signal will be greater than everyone else's signals, conditional on the value $X^{(1)}_i$.

Everyone's signal has an error term with the same distribution, and error terms are independent.

In summary, I would like to calculate the following:

\begin{equation}
\textrm{Prob}(X^{(2)}_i > X^{(2)}_{j}, \textrm{for all } j\neq i\mid X^{(1)}_i).
\end{equation}

If someone can help me with how to approach this problem, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: When you say that there is parameter $a$, do you actually mean that there are $K$ separate parameters $a_1,\ldots,a_K$? Are they independent?

Comment: For each person, there is a  seperate $a_i$, yes. They are independent, but all come from standard uniform distribution $a_i \sim U[0,1]$ for all $i \in K$.

Comment: Ok. I submitted an edit (which waits to be reviewed) to your question clarifying that point, and also using $\LaTeX$.